# How to count duration of answering questions in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

I have 2-step quiz in Google Forms. (Spherical quiz in the vacuum, example doesn't matter).

Is it possible to record in answer spreadsheet timestamps of *opening 2nd step and submitting it* or answering duration?

Answer (score 0):

Hello DmitryLogvinenko,

This can't be achieved easily, so the first answer is: No, you can't do it.
Second Answer is you may use a workaround that is quite farfetched under some conditions:
If you can be sure that user will only acces to your google form with a link that you give them and not by embedding the form in a site, you can automatically create short Urls for all the users that will answer the form and give them these specifics short URL to answer it. These short URL are capable of telling you when they were hit (that's the equivalent to when the user opened the form) and directly in your form you have the timestamp on when the form was submitted so you can do the delta. Of course you need to have a correlation between the submitted URL and the form answer, that can be performed in 2 differents way:
- you know who has the short URL you gave too and in the form you have proceeded to the retrieval of the username (only available in google apps for business)
- the short url do not point to an empty form, but a prefilled form with a specific field that will do the link.

So yes there is a possible workaround, but good luck to implement it!